# French dictionary on Android that works offline

Tags: android, dictionary, french

At my stage of learning, I find having a quick-lookup French-English dictionary very valuable. I use my mobile dictionary app on Android while reading or watching videos. I know that some people say it's better to read without stopping to look up words, but I find that as long as I can look up an unfamiliar word quickly, then it's a big benefit. Plus, I often don't recognize irregular verbs as such until I look them up. However, I need to find a better app. I have a French dictionary for my mobile, but I don't like it so much, and it crashes a lot.

The ideal dictionary app would have the following:

- Works offline, ideally
- Quick to look up a word--if it takes more than a few seconds, it's too slow
- IPA pronunciation listed.
- Finds irregular verbs by entering conjugated forms.
- Some form of history. It would be amazing if you could export history to Anki or otherwise do SRS drill with history. This should definitely be a thing.
- Potential for FR-ENG (most important), ENG-FR, or FR-FR

Is there an app that does the above? I would gladly pay for it. There are plenty of apps on the Play store, but many of them are missing essential features like IPA I don't have time to try them all and find out they aren't good (like my current one).

Comment: I used to take a look at reverso (the website) when I needed it for english learning purpose, I think they do have an app, did you try this already ?

Comment: Reverso doesn't work offline. I know that might not seem important to everyone, but I spent over 24 hours on airplanes the last week, and that's great time for reading and watching.

Comment: [french.se] is about the French language, not about Android apps. [We don't do well with resource requests](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/575/politique-sur-les-demandes-de-ressources-policy-on-resource-list-questions), even if we haven't been consistent with closing them in the past. I'm migrating this question to a site which is better suited for app recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Word Reference meets most of those needs. I also use Linguee a lot which lists real examples of usage (although they seem to be biased towards government documents and the like rather than literature). Both apps allow you to enter either both French and English words without the need to specify the language. You can download a dictionary so you can use Linguee offline.

Comment: Eh, WR is not a great app, at least on Android. It's just a very thin layer over the regular site (and for that reason doesn't work offline). Might as well just use your browser

Comment: +1 for Word Reference, but indeed it does not work offline. I use Google Translate (with downloaded dicts ) when I need a offline "dictionary".

Comment: +1 for Word Reference, but indeed it does not work offline. I use Google Translate (with downloaded dicts ) when I need a offline "dictionary".

Comment: I've edited my post to say that Linguee can be used offline.